# Getting past a pylint test

Tags: python

When I do a pylint check on my code it says i have problems with my return statements. This is my code:

```
board = [['X', ' ', 'O'], ['X', 'O', ' '], ['X', ' ', ' ']]

def winner(board):
    """noughts and crosses game and checks if a row or column or diagonal is a winner"""
    row_ = []
    for row_number in range(3):
        row_.append(board[row_number])
    column_ = []
    for col_number in range(3):
        column_.append(list(board[0][col_number] + board[1][col_number] + board[2][col_number]))
    diagonal_0 = []
    diagonal_1 = []
    for selected_diagonal in range(2):
        if selected_diagonal == 0:
            diagonal_0.append(list(board[0][0] + board[1][1] + board[2][2]))
        diagonal_1.append(list(board[0][2] + board[1][1] + board[2][0]))
    total = row_ + column_ + diagonal_0 + diagonal_1
    for line in total:
        if line[0] == line[1] == line[2]:
            if line[0] == 'X':
                return 'X'
            elif line[0] == 'O':
                return 'O'
            elif line[0] == ' ':
                return None
            break
```

This is the error I get

```
************* Module source
R: 81, 0: Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. (inconsistent-return-statements)

***Error***
Sorry, but your code doesn't pass the pylint style checks.
```

Comment: try removing the break statement and try again.

Comment: the `break` is dead code, there is no way to get there, pylint found it wants you to remove it.

Comment: Hahahah thanks Albin Paul! can't believe i missed that!! but do you have any advice for the second error i'm getting??

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the code is

```
else:
    return line[0]
break
```

if you remove the else and just keep the `return line[0]` has same meaning.

and **break at the end is of no use after return!**

Answer (score 1):

```py
# previous lines ...
for line in total:
        if line[0] == line[1] == line[2]:
            if line[0] == 'X':
                return 'X'
            elif line[0] == 'O':
                return 'O'
            elif line[0] and line[1] and line[2] != ' ':
                return line[0]
            return something
            break
        return something
```

This will work. Please try it.

`break` breaks out of a loop. Removing the else, will not affect anything.

**Just do proper indentation of the `return line[0]`**

Run the code and test it.

The second error will also be removed.

Comment: Thanks! and if possible do you have anyadvice for the second pylint error??

Comment: write a condition for returning line[0]

Comment: and no need of returning None .
            ```elif line[0] and line[1] and line[2] == ' ':
                return None

Comment: If i use the new code which i put in my question i'm still getting the second error. Am I missing something??

Comment: Again see updated answer.  Return something appropriate in other cases. It depends on where you are using the function